# Unable to read 'getBoundingClientRect' property of a non-null object

Tags: javascript, html

**HTML:**

```
<div id="center_div">
    <div id="cCarousel">
        <div class="arrow" id="prev" style="display:none;"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></div>
        <div class="arrow" id="next" style="display:none;"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
        <div id="carousel-vp">
            <div id="cCarousel-inner"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**Javascript:**

```
const prev = document.querySelector("#prev");
const next = document.querySelector("#next");

const dict = {"img url 1": "Description 1",
              "img url 2": "Description 2",
              "img url 3": "Description 3",
              "img url 4": "Description 4",
              "img url 5": "Description 5",
              "img url 6": "Description 6"};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
   login();
   generateCarouselContent();
});

function login(){
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "../backend.php", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            if(xhr.responseText.includes("success"))
               initializeCarousel();
        }
    };
    var data = "input=change_login_status" + "&emp=" + localStorage.getItem("empno");
    xhr.send(data);
}

function initializeCarousel() {
    let cCarouselInner = document.getElementById("cCarousel-inner");

    function setupCarousel() {
        let carouselVp = document.querySelector("#carousel-vp");
        let carouselInnerWidth = cCarouselInner.getBoundingClientRect().width;
        let leftValue = 0;

        const totalMovementSize =
            parseFloat(
                document.querySelector(".cCarousel-item").getBoundingClientRect().width,
                10
            ) +
            parseFloat(
                window.getComputedStyle(cCarouselInner).getPropertyValue("gap"),
                10
        );

        prev.addEventListener("click", () => {
            if (!leftValue == 0) {
                leftValue -= -totalMovementSize;
                cCarouselInner.style.left = leftValue + "px";
            }
        });

        next.addEventListener("click", () => {
            const carouselVpWidth = carouselVp.getBoundingClientRect().width;
            if (carouselInnerWidth - Math.abs(leftValue) > carouselVpWidth) {
                leftValue -= totalMovementSize;
                cCarouselInner.style.left = leftValue + "px";
            }
        });

        const mediaQuery510 = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 510px)");
        const mediaQuery770 = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 770px)");

        mediaQuery510.addEventListener("change", mediaManagement);
        mediaQuery770.addEventListener("change", mediaManagement);

        let oldViewportWidth = window.innerWidth;

        function mediaManagement() {
            const newViewportWidth = window.innerWidth;

            if (leftValue <= -totalMovementSize && oldViewportWidth < newViewportWidth) {
                leftValue += totalMovementSize;
                cCarouselInner.style.left = leftValue + "px";
                oldViewportWidth = newViewportWidth;
            } else if (
                leftValue <= -totalMovementSize &&
                oldViewportWidth > newViewportWidth
            ) {
                leftValue -= totalMovementSize;
                cCarouselInner.style.left = leftValue + "px";
                oldViewportWidth = newViewportWidth;
            }
        }

        setInterval(autoPlayCarousel, 2500); // Auto play interval
        leftValue = 0;

        function autoPlayCarousel() {
            const carouselVpWidth = carouselVp.getBoundingClientRect().width;
            if (carouselInnerWidth - Math.abs(leftValue) > carouselVpWidth) {
                leftValue -= totalMovementSize;
                cCarouselInner.style.left = leftValue + "px";
            } else {
                leftValue = 0;
                cCarouselInner.style.left = leftValue + "px";
            }
        }
    }

    console.log(cCarouselInner); //shows the element, as described below

    if (cCarouselInner) {
        setupCarousel();
    } else {
        setTimeout(initializeCarousel, 100);
    }
}

function generateCarouselContent() {
   let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open("POST", "../backend.php", true);
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   xhr.onload = function () {
       if (xhr.status === 200) {
           prev.style.display="block";
           next.style.display="block";
           const carouselInner = document.getElementById("cCarousel-inner");
           const dictKeys = Object.keys(dict);

           // Randomly select 3 unique keys from the dict
           const selectedKeys = getRandomElements(dictKeys, 3);

           selectedKeys.forEach((key, index) => {
               const card = createCarouselCard(index + 1, dict[key], key);
               carouselInner.appendChild(card);
           });
        }
    };
    var data = "input=check_if_file_exists" + "&emp=" + localStorage.getItem("empno");
    xhr.send(data);
}

function getRandomElements(arr, num) {
    const shuffled = arr.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());
    return shuffled.slice(0, num);
}

function createCarouselCard(index, text, key) {
    const card = document.createElement("article");
    card.classList.add("cCarousel-item");

    const img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = key;
    img.alt = "file";

    const infos = document.createElement("div");
    infos.classList.add("infos");

    const h3 = document.createElement("h3");
    h3.textContent = `Fact ${index} / 3`;

    const span = document.createElement("span");
    span.textContent = text;

    infos.appendChild(h3);
    infos.appendChild(span);

    card.appendChild(img);
    card.appendChild(infos);

    return card;
}
```

---

**What the above code does:**

It randomly selects any 3 elements from `dict` and creates three carousel cards to showcase the contents. After that the carousel keeps on playing indefinitely. Along with that, the user can click on `#next` to go to the next card, and `#prev` to go to the previous.

---

**The problem that I am facing:**

The above code runs but only sometimes!! I tried `console.log(cCarouselInner)`, which shows the correct output every time in this format:

```
<div id="cCarousel-inner">
    <article class="cCarousel-item">
        <img src="img url 2" alt="file">
        <div class="infos">
            <h3>Fact 1 / 3</h3>
            <span>Description 2</span>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="cCarousel-item">
        <img src="img url 3" alt="file">
        <div class="infos">
            <h3>Fact 2 / 3</h3>
            <span>Description 3</span>
        </div>
    </article>
    <article class="cCarousel-item">
        <img src="img url 1" alt="file">
        <div class="infos">
            <h3>Fact 3 / 3</h3>
            <span>Description 1</span>
        </div>
    </article>
</div>
```

But I keep getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getBoundingClientRect')

in the line

```
const totalMovementSize = 
      parseFloat(
         document.querySelector(".cCarousel-item").getBoundingClientRect().width,
         10
      ) +
      parseFloat(
         window.getComputedStyle(cCarouselInner).getPropertyValue("gap"),
         10
      );
```

Again, after a couple of reloads, the code suddenly works! Why is this error occuring? Please guide me.

Comment: You're calling that method in several places. Which one is getting the error?

Comment: The thing is I can see a lot of code that has nothing to do with the problem you mentioned. It really helps us to provide our insights if you provide minimal code where the issue is occurring.

Comment: The error tells you that the object is `null`. You claim it isn't. I'm definitely going to side with the error because I sincerely doubt you're literally the first person to experience an error where a non-null value is considered null.

Comment: This is not a valid way to shuffle an array: `arr.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random());`. The comparison function has to return consistent results to create a total ordering.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array

Comment: Also, I am guessing that the `setupCarousel()` function is being called before the DOM has fully loaded the necessary elements. This may result in the `getBoundingClientRect()` method being called on a null element, causing the error you're seeing sometimes. If this is the case try introducing a [zero delay setTImeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful)

Comment: @VLAZ yes, this is because I tried logging the `cCarouselInner` before it goes to `setupCarousel()`, and it shows the element correctly

Comment: Are you sure the error is related to `cCarouselInner`?

Comment: @mandy8055 The parent function `login()` is already being run inside `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){...});`

Comment: @abhishek_6198 all that tells you is that it's not `cCarouselInner` that is `null`. Or that you misread the logs. I can confidently say that the JS runtime doesn't randomly claim that non-null values are null. If it did, we'd have more than the single report from you.

Comment: @VLAZ I am using the `getBoundingClientRect` on the `cCarouselInner` object (`let carouselInnerWidth = cCarouselInner.getBoundingClientRect().width`), whereas when I log the `cCarouselInner`, the element is there!!

Comment: @abhishek_6198 you have *five* calls to `getBoundingClientRect`. You haven't demonstrated or apparently even investigated which is at fault. Provide a [mcve] that clearly shows what you say is true and a non-null value is treated incorrectly as null.

Comment: @VLAZ Oh, I am so sorry. The error is occuring in the line `parseFloat(document.querySelector(".cCarousel-item").getBoundingClientRect().width,10`)`